# how to use `dgrid3d` in `gnuplot` correctly?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I've got a data file which contains a bunch of `x`, `y` and `z` **points**. I'd like to use `gnuplot` to plot out these points `with pm3d`but this requires me to turn on `set dgrid 10,10,1` (the number should be different). THe problem is that my data gets warped (the points don't lay on the `pm3d`surface when I plot them out together).

How should I use `dgrid3d`? The points are generated from a `c++` program, so I can choose the x and y spacing myself.

My data looks like this:

```
# X    Y    Z
  1    2    3
  2    2    4
  ...
```

I'd like it to be a colored surface that runs through these points in 3D space. The `x` and `y` data is spaced evenly, while the `z` data is a function of `x` and `y` points.

Comment: 1. Could you post a small section of your data file
2. What should your final plot actually look like? Points in 3D space, a contour map, connected points, ...

Comment: wow. this question has the 'popular question' badge (1k views) and not one upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have your data available in a file `Data.dat` then give this a try:

```
set dgrid3d 10,10
set style data lines
set pm3d 
splot "Data.dat" pal
```

- The `dgrid3d` tells gnuplot how many entries there are in the x- and y-direction (those are the two comma separated parameters)
- The `style data lines` lets gnuplot plot the result with lines instead of points
- The `pm3d` fills the surface with a color (if you leave this away you will just see the lines)
- `pal` makes the lines appear in the color of the specified value

There are much more options you can set, but i find those the most relevant.

Comment: Ok, my question was actually aimed at how to use the `dgrid3d`? What should the numbers be?

Comment: The numbers specify how many elements there are in x- and y-direction. So if you have 20 x-values and 10 y-values then specify the parameters in dgrid as 20, 10

Comment: I've got 100x100 data, but when I use `dgrid3d 100,100,1` this delivers a distorted plot (the plot is everaged out at some points). Using `dgrid3d 100,100,3` gives the a surface that passes throug the points, but the surface is raggedy where it shouldn't be.

Comment: AFAIK dgrid3d only takes two parameters if you want to specify the number of rows and columns...

Comment: The third parameter in dgrid3d is the norm used for computing the distance. If you want to minimize the Euclidean distance, use "2", which corresponds to an L2 norm. This matches our intuitive concept of straight-line distance between two points.